# Why the preview tab is not working properly in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

After the new chrome update(123.0.6312.60), I am facing an issue where I can't view HTML page in the preview tab. I tried out many way still encountering same error for a week. Is this problem from chrome side or my side.

[Preview tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50J2i.png)
[Response tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxfP1.png)

[Edge Browser Preview tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbNqq.png)

Comment: The response shown is not proper HTML, looks like the output was transformed with [php_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: I attached my response tab also.

Comment: Which probably get's auto url_decoded. You need to start with checking the RAW response you are receiving/sending back. Are you in control of the response being sent back?

Comment: But it is working perfectly in edge browser.

Comment: Unsure then what you want to do? If you think this is a bug in Chrome, then you should open a ticket with Chrome's support. This is not a support forum - [ask]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.